# C# Check One Drive For Update To WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, auto-update

I am using .net 4.5 and am deploying an .exe to several people.  I am wanting to code in the form launch a way to check onedrive for an udpated version.

I see the built in auto-updater can deploy versions from the local machine, but I did not see in the MSDN that it can deploy from web.

What viable options do I have for a winform to check for updates and auto-download if avaliable?

Comment: You could add a batch file to the users startup or login script.  it's much easier to update files when those files are not in use, so don't try when the application is already running.

Comment: how about clickonce?

Comment: @Neil - do not have access to edit startup files on users computers

Comment: @Steve - I saw where clickonce could update from a local copy but not from the web (such as one drive).  Is it capable to do a web update?

Comment: How about a batch file that the user clicks on to run the application (instead of the .exe), and before running, it does xcopy /y from the onedrive location ?

Comment: @Neil - if that is my only option, I believe that would suffice.  However, I would prefer something built into the C# syntax that can auto-check and auto-download the updated version.

Comment: Onedrive isn't really 'the web' is it?  It's a location on your hard drive that is synchronised to the cloud.  If a file changes in the cloud (your application), it will (at some point) be copied to the local drive.

Comment: But the onedrive account is only "linked" to my local PC.  No other machines will have the credentials that "log in" to the onedrive account.  Only a publicly shared download URL.

Comment: You can probably come up with some really complicated c# application that takes weeks of development and does all the error checking you need, or you can write 3 lines of batch file that will work for the 'several' people who use your application.

Comment: I've not used OneDrive like that, but I bet you can add your shared URL to their OneDrive, like DropBox does, can't you?

Comment: What about an option like this --
 note I am not the author, just found it in google search --http://www.nerdparadise.com/programming/csharpautoupdateapp